# ReactJs: how to call useEffect to set Current Image index to 0 if new images are passed

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an image component that takes an array of `images`. The problem I have is that if I go to the second image in the array and then click on another product and load in a new array of images, the `currentI`  will remain on the second image, likewise if I click on the 3rd image and load in new images the `currentIndex` will remain on the 3rd index.

How can I reset the `currentIndex` to 0 when a new array of images is passed through?

```
const Images = ({ alt, images, thumb }) => {
  const initialImages = images && images.split(',')
  const [ currentIndex, setCurrentIndex ] = useState(0)
  const [ imgs, setImgs ] = useState(initialImages)

  useEffect(() => {
    setImgs(initialImages)
  }, [initialImages])

  const handleNextImage = () => {
    const resetIndex = currentIndex === imgs.length - 1;

    const index = resetIndex ? 0 : currentIndex + 1;

    // assign the logical index to current image index that will be used in render method
    setCurrentIndex(index);
  }

  const handlePrevImage = () => {
    const resetToVeryBack = currentIndex === 0;

    const index = resetToVeryBack ? imgs.length - 1 : currentIndex - 1;

    // assign the logical index to current image index that will be used in render method
    setCurrentIndex(index);
  }
  return (
    <Wrap>

      <Grid>
      <ImgWrap>
        <ImgLazy src={imgs[currentIndex]} thumb={thumb} alt={alt} />
      </ImgWrap>
      <ImgIndex>
        {imgs.length > 1 && imgs.map((img,index) => 
          <Bullet key={index} active={currentIndex === index} />
        )}
      </ImgIndex>
      </Grid>
      </Wrap>
  )
}

export default Images
```

Comment: `setCurrentIndex(0)` in your effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As was stated, when images change, you can call `setCurrentIndex`, but if you try that, I suspect you'll have issues where the index is constantly reset to `0`. The reason why has to do with how your effect is set up.

Your effect has in its dependencies Array `initialImages`, which is an Array you get from splitting `images`, which appears to be a string. Each time your `Images` function runs, this `initialImages` will be a different `Array` object, because `split` called multiple times on the same string will return a different Array object. Because it's a different Array each time, not only when the `images` prop changes but also whenever state changes, your effect will re-run because the dependencies are different.

You should set the `images` prop as your dependency instead. That way you can call `setCurrentIndex(0)` inside of your effect without constantly triggering a reset of that value.

```
const Images = ({ alt, images, thumb }) => {
  const initialImages = images && images.split(',')
  const [ currentIndex, setCurrentIndex ] = useState(0)
  const [ imgs, setImgs ] = useState(initialImages)

  useEffect(() => {
    setImgs(initialImages)
    setCurrentIndex(0)
  }, [images])

  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
useEffect(() => {
  setImgs(initialImages)
  setCurrentIndex(0)
}, [images])
```

Your `initialImages` and `currentIndex` have different state values, so in the `useEffect` that has `initialImages` in its dependency array, you must also update the `currentIndex` to achieve the desired result. This "effect" will run every time the `images` prop is updated. Perhaps `imageUrlArray` would be a better variable name than `initialImages`.

EDIT: Since React cannot distinguish arrays in the dependency array and will likely run the effect every time a state value/prop changes, you should set `[images]` as the dependency array, so it properly runs the `useEffect` callback whenever that `images` prop is updated.

Comment: I thought this would work also but it doesn't allow me to move between images, it's stuck on the currentIndex(0) always